# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 when invoking getWindowHandles()

Tags: java, selenium

I am running into an unexpected issue with one of my scripts.

I have a an application that can publish news on a number of different levels such as an organisational level and levels lower down in the organisation.  Depending on your occupation only certain people can publish a news article on the org level.

I have written the scripts on this level and they all work.

I copied the scripts and slightly modified them to publish the news at a lower level and this is where I am seemingly running into trouble.  One particular script adds an image into the news article and to do that you need to manipulate a series of modal dialog windows.  This workflow is identical to the org level.

However when I run the script at the lower level I get an error which states:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
at com.desire2learn.dev.pages.CreateItemNewsPage.get_window_ids(CreateItemNewsPage.java:338)
at com.desire2learn.dev.tests.NewsItemsUnitLevelTest.publish_news_with_image(NewsItemsUnitLevelTest.java:379)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The code it slips up on is the following:

```
public void get_window_ids(){

    //Get the handles for the main window and the popup window for the upload button
            try {
                Set<String> AllWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
                System.out.println(AllWindowHandles.size()+  " distinct windows: " + AllWindowHandles);
                window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
                System.out.println("\nwindow 1 is " + window1+"\n");
                window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
                System.out.println("\nwindow 2 is " + window2+"\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

It trips up on window2.

However this same method works on the org level.  I also notice that it says there are 2 distinct windows at org level:

> 2 distinct windows: [CDwindow-13376ec5-43ac-4668-a2f9-50660e3b09cf,
>   CDwindow-d3e9e6eb-954a-4bf8-ba28-b30049ed85d8]

Also when I debug on the unit level iget the following:

> 2 distinct windows: [CDwindow-13376ec5-43ac-4668-a2f9-50660e3b09cf,
>   CDwindow-d3e9e6eb-954a-4bf8-ba28-b30049ed85d8]

Running the script I get only 1 distinct window however....very strange.

It baffles me. Can someone give me a pointer or am I just doing something stupid here?

**UPDATE**

I changed a configuration setting in the application which controls whether popups are displayed as modal or nonmodal popups and it seems to resolve the issue.  The popup still displays that it is nonModalDialog however.  So it appears that nothing has changed.  Except the script does not work when the conf item is disabled and works when it is disabled.

Comment: You are getting error because the resulting set has only one element and you are trying to get the second.

Comment: Yes I just found that out right now.  I added `code    System.out.println(AllWindowHandles.size()+  " distinct windows: " + AllWindowHandles);` and it says at the org level there are 2 distinct windows but at the lower level there is only 1 distinct window.  I'll edit the question to reflect this.  But I did check the window ids on the lower level and they appear to be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard this question I have resolved it.  The issue was with Modal and non modal windows and my script was configured for nonmodal popups.  I couldnt see that the scripts I ran in a different part of the application had beed configured for modal dialogs breaking my script in the process.

Appologies for wasting peoples time on this.

Comment: No need to apologize. Just answer your own question if you managed to resolve it and accept it so other people with the same issue will know how to solve it.